# `implicit_plot` complex function in SageMath

Tags: python, plot, complex-numbers, sage

I'd like to plot the circle described by the equation `|z - 1| = 1` for complex `z`. I expected the following to work:

```
f(x, y) = abs(x +  i * y -1)

implicit_plot(f(x, y) - 1, xrange=(-2, 2), yrange=(-2, 2))
```

but it fails with:

```
TypeError: unable to coerce to a real number
```

which seems strange, since `abs` does't return a complex number. The following fails with the same error:

```
f(x, y) = abs(x +  i * y -1)

implicit_plot((f(x, y) - 1).real_part(), xrange=(-2, 2), yrange=(-2, 2))
```

What's the right way to plot this function?

Comment: Did you try using `j` instead of `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command defining `f` defines it as a symbolic function:

```py
sage: f(x, y) = abs(x +  i * y - 1)

sage: f
(x, y) |--> abs(x + I*y - 1)
sage: f(x, y)
abs(x + I*y - 1)

sage: parent(f)
Callable function ring with arguments (x, y)
sage: parent(f(x, y))
Symbolic Ring
```

The plotting commands to plot `f(x, y) - 1` as in the question
trigger internal code to convert the required expression
into a "fast-callable function", which fails.

A workaround, valid for many plotting problems in Sage,
is to **use a lambda function** instead.

For this, just introduce `lambda x, y:` before the expression
in `x` and `y` to be plotted:

```
sage: implicit_plot(lambda x, y: f(x, y) - 1, xrange=(-2, 2), yrange=(-2, 2))
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 1 graphics primitive
```

[image: Implicit plot of a circle using its complex numbers definition]